# OSX HDMI resolution working very strangely

Tags: macos, resolution, hdmi, osx-mavericks

Hi i've a really strange problem with an AOC v22 monitor plugged in to a Mavericks Macbook pro. The screen's resolution is 1680x1050 which OSX seems to correctly identify. However the monitor screen reports it's running at 1648x1030. It's definitely wrong as the picture is fuzzy and goes off the screen too.

It's plugged in via HDMI so I thought it would pick the correct resolution itself. There's no options on the monitor to select another resolution so I'm a bit at a loss how to correct it.

Any advice would be great - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In the monitors settings menu (not on the computer but the monitor itself) have you seen if there is an auto adjust setting, or tried a different cable?

Edit: providing the model of the monitor in your question would help the troubleshooting process (whether its a + or not in this case).  Also this sounds like an overscan issue with the mac.

From http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1198351.html

> user: **ankh**
>   Sep 12, 2011, 02:22 PM
>
> there is an over scan/under scan option that can be adjusted. That might do the trick.
>
> http://www.google.com/search?q=AOC+monitor+mac+overscan
>
> Do look for that. I hit that problem with an AOC V22+, with a 2007 Mini, using a VGA cable, and >was able to solve it in the System Preferences/Display setting by checking the "Overscan" box. >It's still checked, I'm now using a HDMI cable, still working.
>
> I think I recall some confusion because in the AOC menus, only when set for a VGA, there is also >an overscan setting there -- that's not available when using HDMI.
>
> When my 2011 Mini arrives I'll probably face this problem again

Comment: thanks for that. Unfortunately there's only an under scan option and that's disabled. I think because I'm using HDMI. Can't see to find another way to do it. Might have to try with a VGA cable instead.

Comment: ah ok i've just realised what you said. I think i have to do it with the VGA cable as the HDMI I presume is pushing a HD resolution whereas the VGA can be changed. I'll give it a go :)